# Is there a way to find a deviation between a1=[] and a2=[] in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, statistics, standard-deviation, deviation

We have these arrays in python:

```
a1 = [0, 1, 2, 3]
a2 = [0, 1.1, 2.2, 3.1]
```

and want to find the deviation between a1 and a2. And sorry, we do not know what's such a type of deviation is named, but probably some of you do know.

Comment: Do you mean sum of squared differences? Sum of distance between pairs of points? It's definitely not a standard deviation, that's for sure.

Comment: Yeah, it could be something like that @enke

Comment: The point is, that we have a theoretical dataset there is exact, and an experimental dataset, and want to compare them

Comment: @j1-lee Yeah, that is of course not a coincidence, we are working together, and he told me that answer, however, I was thinking that there must be something to tell the difference between multiple numbers. But probably sorry for asking a stupid question...

Answer (score 0):

You can find the sum of squared distances (as clarified in the comments) by using `sum()` and `zip()`:

```py
distance = sum([(elem1 - elem2)**2 for elem1, elem2 in zip(a1, a2)])
```